# windows 7 - when I open a folder in windows explorer (details view) via autohotkey focus is on the columns header

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, autohotkey

So when I press enter the list is reordered instead of the highlighted file/folder to open/ run.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I has having the same issue, this is why I was searching and found your question here. I'm also using AutoHotkey and also have a hotkey for an explorer window which includes the "Shift" key. Your first answer helped my and I thought about it again.

I figured out, it's NOT AutoHotkey causing the problem, but explorer itself when it is launched while holding the "Shift" key down. You can confirm this by opening a directory while holding the Shift key down within explorer. This causes the same issue.

Anyway, unfortunately i still don't have any other solution to this than NOT using the Shift hey for the hotkey to open a directory.

Comment: I did "reporI it" -see : http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/63633-run-c-weirdness-on-windows-7-x64/ for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Well - I was not clear (cause I was confused myself) - what was happening was that the autohotkey command `run` as in say :`+#M::run, F:\M U S I C` would give focus to the columns header instead of the explorer pane - so probably I should report this there.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> takes the focus from the column header to the file content area.

You could add that to your AutoHotkey script which opens the Windows explorer.